# How to Use new firebase authentication with angularfire for email and password Login

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application with firebase and I am looking for the user authentication with the new migrated google's firebase with angularfire.

I tried to search in the API provided but was not able to find any examples for the login mechanism using angularfire. I am just looking for email and password login.

Thereafter i tried with the legacy angularfire but some of the methods are no longer supported. can someone provide me with an example for the email/password login?

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation on migrating for the new firebase with AngularFire.

Make sure you are using [2.0.0+ firebase version](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and follow this [migration guide](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md).

Besides that you just need to follow the documentation for firebase 3.x.x provided on firebase webpage.